# Tomcat environment variable in shared.loader triggers warning

Tags: java, spring, java-8, tomcat8

In catalina.properties file I have set the `shared.loader` value as follows,

```
shared.loader="${APP_HOME}/UI/shared/lib/*.jar"
```

Tomcat is starting properly and loading the jars in the specified folder as well, I know because if I specify incorrect path then application is not deployed.

But when I restart Tomcat, I get following warning

```
Aug 06, 2018 8:26:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/${APP_HOME}/UI/shared/lib], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
```

Using absolute path resolves the problem but we would like to use the APP_HOME environment variable as its configurable.

So, how to resolve this issue?

Update:
I have tried using quotes(") around the path as well but result is same.

Answer (score 0):

In `${catalina.base}/conf/catalina.properties`,

You get,

```
common.loader="${catalina.base}/lib","${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar","${catalina.home}/lib","${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar"
```

Change it with,

```
common.loader=${catalina.base}/lib,${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar,${catalina.home}/lib,${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar
```

It seems a bug according to the [Apache page [55620]](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55620)

Comment: I have tried using quotes as well but result is same.

Comment: @SachinGorade you will remove the quotes, won't use!